# Changing user's password and adding users in Geoserver using REST service

Tags: geoserver, c#, rest, geoserver-rest-api

I want to change user's password (e.g. for `admin` user) and create a new one using `Geoserver`'s `REST` `API`. Is this possible? I tried to look for some solution in their [DOCUMENTATION](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/), but nothing found about users and passwords...